# iOS Keychain Value Nil

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I'm using [this](https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift) iOS library to handle storing and getting values in the iOS Keychain. Below is the main code I'm using to store a value in the keychain.

```
let email: String = emailTextField.text!
let keychain = KeychainSwift()
keychain.set(email, forKey: "email")
```

I'm trying to set values in the keychain to store the users email and password. The code above is only for email. Right after that code I have set a breakpoint and running `p keychain.get("email")` returns `nil` in the console. `p keychain.lastResultCode` returns `-25300`. Even after trying to quit the app and get the data again it still doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas why it would be returning `nil`? Just for reference I'm using the iPhone Simulator running Xcode 8.

Comment: have you turn on the keychain sharing capability?

Comment: @koropok No I hadn't. That seems to work now. Why was this required? Did give me an error when enabling it about my App ID but that is probably because I haven't registered it or anything like that. Also feel free to leave an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to turn on Keychain Sharing capability in order for the simulator to work.

This seems to be a known bug. You can read up more on here.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/179846